# How to get Sphericity in R for a nested within subject design?

Tags: r, anova, sphericity

Thank you for reading. I am trying to get sphericity values for a purely within subject design. I have been unable to use ezANOVA, or Anova(). Anova works if I add a between subject factor, but I have been unable to get sphericity for a purely within subject design. Any advice?

I already read the R newsletter, fox chapter appendix, EZanova, and whatever I could find online.

My original ANOVA

```
anova(aov(resp ~ sucrose*citral, random =~1 | subject, data = p12bl, subset = exps==1)) 
anova(aov(resp ~ sucrose*citral, random =~1 | subject/sucrose*citral, data = p12bl, subset = exps==1))

> str(subset(p12bl, exps==1))
'data.frame':   192 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ exps     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Order    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ threshold: Factor w/ 2 levels " Suprathreshold",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SET      : Factor w/ 2 levels " A"," B": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ subject  : Factor w/ 16 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ stim     : chr  "S1C1" "S1C1" "S1C1" "S1C1" ...
 $ resp     : num  6.01 5.63 0 2.57 6.81 ...
 $ id       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ X1       : Factor w/ 1 level "S": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sucrose  : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X3       : Factor w/ 1 level "C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ citral   : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

subset(p12b,exps==1)
   exps Order       threshold SET observ S1C1 S1C2 S1C3 S1C4 S2C1 S2C2 S2C3 S2C4 S3C1 S3C2 S3C3 S3C4 S4C1 S4C2 S4C3 S4C4
1     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      1  6.0  7.1  7.5  8.6 15.0 15.4 15.0 13.1 16.9   13 13.1 16.5   24   16   21   20
2     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      2  5.6  0.8  4.0  5.6  5.6 11.3 12.9 14.5 18.5   15 12.9 14.5   24   26   29   28
3     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      3  0.0  0.0  1.7  0.0  5.0  8.4  8.4  5.0 11.7   20 18.5 16.8   29   37   37   30
4     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      4  2.6  3.3  9.1 16.3  5.4 10.0  9.6 16.8 13.5   12 22.2 23.1   19   20   22   23
5     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      5  6.8  5.3 15.4 14.5 11.5  8.3 14.5 14.2  8.9   17 11.2 15.1   24   23   19   19
6     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      6  2.6  2.8  2.6  5.2 13.4 15.6 13.7 13.0 13.7   15 16.0 18.9   22   24   25   25
7     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      7  1.3  5.8 10.2  9.8 11.9 12.3 17.7 16.7 11.4   19 19.2 21.1   16   19   18   19
8     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      8  2.0  5.6  3.9  2.0  4.9  5.2  7.5  4.9 20.2   21  8.2  9.5   30   26   32   45
9     1     1  Suprathreshold   A      9  9.4 11.3 11.7 12.1 14.7 13.8 12.6 14.9 15.2   15 15.9 13.9   17   18   15   18
10    1     1  Suprathreshold   A     10  4.5 17.8 18.5 21.6  5.8 10.9 17.0 20.2  6.6   10 17.8 18.7   12   12   16   19
11    1     1  Suprathreshold   A     11  9.8 13.0 16.1 18.0 10.5 11.6 15.4 17.3 10.1   14 15.2 16.7   13   15   15   17
12    1     1  Suprathreshold   A     12  9.6 10.4 13.3 11.3 12.1 12.6 13.6 13.6 14.9   16 15.1 16.3   16   18   18   17
```

Sample output

```
ezANOVA( data = subset(p12bl, exps==1)  , dv= .(resp), sid = .(observ), within = .(sucrose,citral), between = NULL, collapse_within = FALSE)
Note: model has only an intercept; equivalent type-III tests substituted.
$ANOVA
          Effect DFn DFd  SSn  SSd     F       p p<.05   pes
1        sucrose   3  33 4953 3263 16.70 9.0e-07     * 0.603
2         citral   3  33  410  553  8.16 3.3e-04     * 0.426
3 sucrose:citral   9  99   56  791  0.77 6.4e-01       0.066
```

Warning messages:
1: You have removed one or more Ss from the analysis. Refactoring "observ" for ANOVA. 
2: Too few Ss for Anova(), reverting to aov(). See "Warning" section of the help on ezANOVA.

Comment: Do you want to look at sphericity or a factor to correct F-values because of violations in sphericity?

Comment: @John I need to see if I need the correction

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
library(ez)
ezANOVA(data=subset(p12bl, exps==1),
  within=.(sucrose, citral),
  wid=.(subject),
  dv=.(resp)
  )
```

and the equivalent aov command, minus sphericity etc, is:

```
aov(resp ~ sucrose*citral + Error(subject/(sucrose*citral)), 
    data= subset(p12bl, exps==1))
```

Here's the equivalent using Anova from car directly:

```
library(car)
df1<-read.table("clipboard", header=T) #From copying data in the question above
sucrose<-factor(rep(c(1:4), each=4))
citral<-factor(rep(c(1:4), 4))
idata<-data.frame(sucrose,citral)

mod<-lm(cbind(S1C1, S1C2, S1C3, S1C4, S2C1, S2C2, S2C3, S2C4, 
        S3C1, S3C2, S3C3, S3C4, S4C1, S4C2, S4C3, S4C4)~1, data=df1)
av.mod<-Anova(mod, idata=idata, idesign=~sucrose*citral)
summary(av.mod)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. however, your response doesn't answer my question. I already mentioned in my post that I already came across the ezANOVA function. I tried it without success. I am also already familiar with the aov notation you metnion.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when using ezANOVA? Whenever I use it, I get a nice table of sphericity tests and GG/HF corrections.
It does not work for ANCOVA models, for this you will need to use the lme4 package, and there are other things to account for variance.

Comment: It would probably help if you put the output of "str(p12bl)" or "str(subset(p12bl, exp2==1))" here.

Comment: @Matt thank you for the very helpful edit. I was trying other things after the ~ except 1 - as in your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, it seems that there's a bug in the current version of ez (v1.6.1). I've tracked it down to the fact that in converting to the formats that Anova() likes, ez was failing to turn something into a factor. I'm not sure whether this was always a bug, or whether Anova() recently changed in a way that broke ez. Regardless, I'm preparing ez v2.0, and this is one of the bug fixes. Stay tuned...

Comment: Thanks Mike, it seems to have happened fairly recently. I just finished an analysis last month using your package and haven't noticed any problems until this question came up.

Comment: @ Matt, I still get the same EZanova warning msg. for Anova I get another error msg: 
Note: model has only an intercept; equivalent type-III tests substituted.
Error in linearHypothesis.mlm(mod, hyp.matrix, SSPE = SSPE, idata = idata, : The error SSP matrix is apparently of deficient rank = 0 < 1

Comment: This may help with the type-III thing https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-October/144240.html ; and I've edited my answer to reflect the updated version of ez, which has changed "sid" to "wid". I don't get your problem with the data you've given me.

Comment: #Try this with the code I've written for the car Anova
#transfer data back to long to perform ezANOVA    
df2<-melt(df1, id.vars="observ", measure.vars=names(df1)[6:21])
df2$suc<-substr(df2$variable,1,2)
df2$cit<-substr(df2$variable,3,4)
df2$observ<-factor(df2$observ)
ez1<-ezANOVA(data=df2,
  within=.(suc, cit),
  wid=.(observ),
  dv=.(value)
  )

Comment: updated ez, but still doesn't work 2: Anova() failed for some reason (maybe there are too few Ss?). should having too few Ss matter?

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 7):

Did you try the `car` package, from John Fox? It includes the function `Anova()` which is very useful when working with experimental designs. It should give you corrected p-value following Greenhouse-Geisser correction and Huynh-Feldt correction. I can post a quick R example if you wonder how to use it.

Also, there is a nice tutorial on the use of R with repeated measurements and mixed-effects model for [psychology experiments and questionnaires](http://www.psych.upenn.edu/~baron/rpsych/rpsych.html); see Section 6.10 about sphericity.

As a sidenote, the Mauchly's Test of Sphericity is available in `mauchly.test()`, but it doesn't work with `aov` object if I remembered correctly. The [R Newsletter](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2007-2.pdf) from October 2007 includes a brief description of this topic.

Comment: I was just about to recommend this.  The ez package relies on car for some analysis.

Comment: Thank you, the R newsletter is where I picked the mlm direction from. alas, I am still figuring how to choose idata idesign for a nested within subject design. I will try to figure out Anova().

Comment: @ John Anova() is supposed to take my aov() object as a model, but for some reason I am having problems making it work.

Comment: @Adam In the on-line help for Anova(), you will find a working example with within- and between-subjects factors; the main caveats of Anova() is that you need to pass idata/idesign parameters in addition to your lm object. Also see this thread on the r-help mailing list, http://j.mp/9lphud.

Comment: @Adam Did you mean the example included in the help file for Anova? In this case, I grabbed the R transcript and put it there, http://j.mp/9pGtKY. HTH

Comment: @chl thank you! for some reason I couldn't find an on-line help for car Anova(). but this example is already in the R off-line help at ?Anova. I am starting to understand this method.

Comment: @Adam Ah ok, my answer was thus a little bit out... What I call on-line is indeed the help() or ? call under R. For external references, you can try http://www.rseek.org/ or http://search.r-project.org/ (much better than directly goggling about R). Also I just this post with a nice illustration: http://j.mp/dnJgW0.

Comment: Here is the correct link, http://j.mp/c6nDvn.

Answer (score 5):

I generally recommend avoiding these types of sphericity tests altogether by using modern mixed modeling methods.  If you are not working with few subjects this will give you a great deal of flexibility in modeling an appropriate covariance structure, freeing you from the strict assumption of sphericity when necessary.  I infer from the `str` output that you have 16 subjects with 12 observations each (I assume balance b/c you areusing clasical method-of-moments tools) which should be enough data to fit a mixed model with structured covariance matrices via (restricted) maximum likelihood.

Without being close to your data I can't offer specific model recommendations, but a place to start in R would be to replace `aov` in your model specifications with `lme` (after `library(nlme)`). The reason this will work is that you have mistakenly provided an `nlme`-style random argument to `aov` (when, as @Matt Albrecht pointed out, an `Error` term would have been approriate).  In nlme, with the random argument set to `~ 1|<your grouping structure>` 
and no `correlation` or `weight` arguments, you are specifying a random intercept for each group, implying the response covariance within groups is `ZGZ' + R = 1G1'+ \sigma^2 I` ==> compound symmetry with between-group variance off-diagonal and between-group variance + within-group variance on the diagonal ==> a spherical structure.  From there you can begin to explore (e.g. using the built-in graphical methods), model, and test (e.g. comparing information criteria or using LRTs for nested models) the various forms of non-sphericity. Some of the tools for the modeling component are:

- Using the `weights` argument to model non-constant variance (diagonals) within or between groups (e.g. error variance changes between sucrose levels).
- Using the `correlation` argument to model non-constant covariance (off-diagonals) within groups (e.g. a structure within a group where residual errors that are closer together in time (e.g. AR1 structure) or space (e.g. Spherical structure) are more similar).
- Modeling random slopes by adding terms to the LHS of the `|` in the `random` formula.

Though the process can be complex with many potential pitfalls, I believe it will lead you to think more about the data generating mechanism, and when combined with careful graphical checks (I recommed `lattice` b/c `nlme` has excellent lattice-based plotting methods -- but `ggplot` works well too) you are likely to have not only a better scientific understanding of the process, but also less biased and more efficient estimators with which to draw inferences.

Answer (score 2):

ez has now been updated to version 2.0. Among other improvements, the bug that caused it to fail to work for this example has been fixed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51126/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-lawrence-how-to-get-sphericity-in-r-for-a-nested-wi).